# Can I capture ISP SNMP information with Wireshark?

Tags: networking, snmp, internet, wireshark, packet-capture

I am trying to do some heavy digging into SNMP, BPI+, ISP networks. Since wireshark can be used to capture network data, would I be able to use it to remotely capture my ISP SNMP agent information and view information being sent through it? Would this only work to capture my interactions alone to the SNMP agent?

I have seen different applications out there during my research such as MIB Browser and MIB Walker, and I am wondering if I could use wireshark to view the same type of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean 'remotely capture'?

If you can get the network traffic to your computer, you can use WinPCAP/WireShark to capture it.

Or if you can get a network device to remotely capture the data using something like http://www.routereflector.com/2013/05/embedded-packet-capture-tcpdump-on-cisco-ios-routers/ and can get it back you can analyse it in WireShark.

Summary: if you control a network link the SNMP queries go over, and the queries are not encrypted, yes you can, otherwise no you can't.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant can I capture SNMP data on the same node as mine on my cable network the same way I can view DHCP info(filtered using bootsp)? I am looking to get the same type of information a SNMP walk would provide. Or would I need to perform some kind of man in the middle capture?

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to view SNMP information with Wireshark, if the information is going through the same network as customer traffic.

However, with properly set up networks, SNMP data is sent only via the management network, which is completely separate from actual customer connections. Therefore you would not see the traffic.

Comment: Please do not add signatures to your answers, your name is already beside them ( http://serverfault.com/help/behavior - section 'Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings').